# JQuery Compare Class of List Items

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

Using JQuery I want to check that each list item has the css class `Complete`. If so, i want to display a button, if not I want to keep the button hidden.

The classes are currently inserted dynamically using PHP when the page loads.

My code so far is;

```
<button id="steps-complete" hidden>Download Now</button>

<ul class="wb-steps">
    <li class="<?php echo $class ?>">Step 1</li>
    <li class="<?php echo $class ?>">Step 2</li>
    <li class="<?php echo $class ?>">Step 3</li>
</ul>

<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    var steps = [];
    jQuery( ".wb-steps li" ).each(function( index ) {
        // successfully displays complete for each list item
        console.log( index + ": " + jQuery( this ).attr('class') );
        // if all stepa have 'complete' show button
        $("#steps-complete").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi jonboy. If you're setting the `li` items classes using PHP, wouldn't it be easier to display that button also on the server side?

Comment: hi @RomiHalasz I'm not sure, i'm not very advanced with either language so thought this would be the easiest way to achieve it.

Comment: Ok, I'll attempt an answer to illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You have the `$class` variable, and its value is set as the class of all list items.

Since you are using PHP to render the page, you can use the same variable to test if the button should be shown or not. So you wouldn't need jQuery in this case, you can just remove that part.

Here's what it would look like:

```
<?php
if (strpos($class, 'Completed') !== false) {
?>
<button id="steps-complete" hidden>Download Now</button>
<?php
}
?>
```

This works in your case because you set the same class to all items.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you need to set to the items a different class for each one, this idea wouldn't work.

Comment: With the way you have currently implemented the code, they will.

Comment: Going by your first comment it won't as I need to set to the items a different class for each one sometimes.

Comment: I was just trying to point out that you may also need to update the way you assign the class to each item.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think based on your example I may decide to use PHP like your recommend

Answer (score 0):

You can simply count the elements to see if all of them have the `complete` class:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $steps = $(".wb-steps li");
    var show = $steps.length === $steps.filter('.complete').length;

    $("#steps-complete")
        .toggle(show)
        .get(0)
        .toggleAttribute('hidden', show);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this but my button still wont display, when I inspect the code it looks like this `<button id="steps-complete" hidden="" style="display: inline-block;">Download Now</button>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's still not working, no errors in the console either. See this image of my current code https://imgur.com/a/n7WenD8 Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

i've made a function to check of the children of the `wb-steps` have a class named john, if not then we show the steps complete

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    if($(".wb-steps").children().not('.john').length = 0){
     console.log("there was a div found with a class named john");
    }else{
      $("#steps-complete").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="steps-complete" hidden>Download Now</button>

<ul class="wb-steps">
    <li class="<?php echo $class ?>">Step 1</li>
    <li class="<?php echo $class ?>">Step 2</li>
    <li class="<?php echo $class ?>">Step 3</li>
</ul>
```